# jqGrid: Link in a cell not clickable, and also not link-like

Tags: jqgrid, hyperlink, cell, jqgrid-formatter

I have used a custom formatter for one of the columns in my jqGrid. Here is the formatter:

```
formatter: function(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    var link = $('<a>', {
        text: 'Click Me'
        href: '#',
        click: function() {
           alert('sdfsfsd');
           // my stuff
        }
    });

    return link[0].outerHTML;
}
```

There are two problems:

- The link is not clickable. When I click the link, the row gets selected! Is there a way to not bypass row selection, but also make the link clickable? [Update: I tried using the beforeSelectRow: function(row, e) { return false;} to disable selection. But still not able to click the link. I can see in the html that the cell value is a link  indeed.]
- The link is not link like, meaning it is not blue/underlined, as usual it looks like. I have not overidden anything in my CSS.

Help much appreciated!

Thanks
Vivek Ragunathan

**UPDATE:** I found that this is not a problem with the grid as such. But the click handler does not get linked with the hyperlink. I also tried this code instead but no luck!

```
var link = $('<a>', {
    text: 'Click Me'
    href: '#'
}).click(function() {
   alert('sdfsfsd');
   // my stuff
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the link is created dynamically (using jquery), and then the *HTML of that object is consumed*, the handler will not be part of the HTML. So in this case, the link has to be created out of string directly:

```
formatter: function(cellvalue, options, row) {
    var handler = "someHandlerDefined(" + options.rowId + ")";
    return "<a href=# onclick='" + handler + "'>Link</a>";
}
```

That worked!